# Resign letter ;How to determine the best way to give notice when manager is absent

Tags: resignation, start-date

I have a problem: I had a very hard time to submit my resign letter. 
And actually my manager is not around until 18/8/2018

And yet, I planned on submitting the letter yesterday but hold back.
I printed and i put yesterday's date on it.

Today, I'm ready to submit it, but never modified the date and I submitted it to the supervisor. My problem is: **should it be a problem regarding who I give it to, and will the date be a problem?**

Comment: Can you re-print it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a HR department, you should ask them about how the process works for your company and whether or not they can accept the resignation on your manager's behalf.

If the starting date for your new job is dependent on your current notice period starting soon, then you need to raise this as a concern.  Otherwise, you might simply be told to wait another week for your manager to return.

Comment: "Whether or not they can accept the letter on your manager's behalf": Legally, any letter sent to the postal address of the company has to be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

The date shouldn't be a problem. If it's questioned just say you made a mistake and you agree that the date should have been a day later.

It's impossible to tell from the information whether or not giving the letter to your supervisor is appropriate. Regardless, as you're clearly concerned, I would suggest speaking to your supervisor.

Something along the lines of asking if it's OK to give the letter to your supervisor or should you give it to someone else?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Hope the date really not a issue. And also when i pass to supervisor, my sentence sound it like resign letters already. " hi Liza i would like to pass you something, this i would like you to help me pass to manager. her face show okie and look noted is a resign letter. I told her if manager want to know the reason i will explain to her personal. And i want to keep it secretly first. She okie never ask me wait til boss. So i think i not at fault right.